# Shopify Carrier Service Callback doesn't send information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, callback, shopify

I'm doing a Shopify App with Rails and I've created a new Carrier service with a requestbin callback:

```
def crearcarrier
carrier_service = {
                name: 'Test Carrier',
                callback_url:"https://requestb.in/tfxxxxx",
                service_discovery: true
              }
ShopifyAPI::CarrierService.create(carrier_service)
end
```

But I don't receive anything in requestbin when I'm doing an order on the checkout.

How can I receive the information of the callback_url on my app?

Answer (score 0):

If you setup a checkout, when you transition to the shipping screen, your callback will get a payload from Shopify with the origin, destination and items to be shipped. If you do not get a payload to your endpoint, check if your carrier service was actually created. Otherwise, your problem is likely with requestbin.